# Use define macro from source file in a Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I would like to use a preprocessor macro defined in one of my source files as a variable in my Makefile. The simplest way to do so would be to use `sed` like program to find the macro. However the macro is defined based on a condition (other macros), so a simple search for that macro can yield multiple results. This snippet may illustrate it:

```
#ifdef FOO
#define BAR 10
#else
#ifdef BAZ
#define BAR 50
#else
#define BAR 100
#endif
#endif
```

How can the Makefile know if `FOO` or `BAZ` are defined in the source files to eventually get the correct value of `BAR` during compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `cpp` (or `cc -E`) for that. The easiest way to use it is to put all macro definitions into a header file, say `macros.h`. You need also a special C file (say `macros.c`), where you only use your macros. Choose a prefix which is easy to filter, like:

```
#include "macros.h"

valueOf_FOO = FOO
valueOf_BAR = BAR
```

Now, you can extract your macro values with

```
$(CC) -E $(CFLAGS) $(OTHER_CFLAGS) macros.c | grep '^valueOf_' | sed 's/valueOf_//'
```

This will print

```
FOO = FOO
BAR = 50
```

to the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

A different take on that issue is to question oneself *why* a C constant has to play a role outside of the compilation process. One then often finds that this constant (and many others) are truly not a constant part of the C program but a configuration item. As such it is worth to consider if such configuration items should really be hidden inside a C source file or if it is cleaner to generate C source out of a better suited configuration format. In my experience every project sligthly larger than *HelloWorld* starts to profit very soon from a clean&controlled separation of concerns (source editing vs. config editing).

Comment: That makes sense and I'd be happy to consider doing something like that. Do you have any reference for how this is usually done?